# Set height of RelativeLayout to match height of Soft Keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I need to set the height of this `RelativeLayout` to match the height of the `Soft Keyboard`. To make sure the `EditText` appears just above the keyboard.

Is it possible to set some kind of Listener to detect every time the keyboard height changes?

[image]

Comment: You can use the View.OnLayoutChangeListener to listen for changes in the layout of a view, including changes in the keyboard height.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to set soft input to match your needs.
try following for a fragment put this line in your fragment's onCreate method:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

You can set multiple modes with a single line like

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

And if you are working in an activity you can just adjust it in your android manifest file for each activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

or
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`
Check which settings suits your needs better between adjustPan, adjustUnspesified, adjustResize or some other soft input options.

Comment: Check out the answer I posted. Works, but with a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that seems to work fine. With only 1 problem. For some reason the `Status Bar` turns white with this piece of code.. Any idea why?

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this.getWindow().getDecorView(), (v, insets) -> {
        
    int keyboardHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom;
        
    //Code logic
        
    return insets;
});
```

How I set the `Status Bar` color:

```
<style name="AppTheme.GuessWord">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```